How to create a global static u8 array with random characters at compile time in rust
I have some cryptographic macro's, that require a key to operate, that encrypt/hash strings/arrays at compile time. Currently the key, which is shared for all cryptographic macro's, is passed to the compiler through an environment variable using std::env!("KEY"). The key is only used internally and as long as it is random and accessible to the program it is fine. To remove one of the parameters passed to the compiler I want to generate this key at compile time, which leads me to the question of how this can be done.
Ideally I want to have a global variable where the key is stored such that it can be used throughout the code base (similar to how std::env! works). Another nice-to-have would be to create the key once the first time it is used, and never change from that point. I would like to prevent the use of an initialization macro to populate they key variable.
Any thoughts on how this can be achieved would be greatly appreciated!

Since you are asking about cryptography, lets get the obvious out of the way: Including "the key" in whatever way during the compilation process is begging for trouble. The compiler will sneak up on you and leak that key due to whatever functionality it deems necessary. Compilers are not built to keep secrets. You're strongly encouraged to only keep public data around during compilation.

Consider writing a build.rs, generating the key and storing it into some certain mod if it's not present?

@user2722968 I'm well aware of this fact, but I'm only using it to prevent fingerprinting of data and do not expect it to hold up against targeted attacks :)

@KirisameIgna would it be possible to output the value generated in a build.rs file to a global static variable?

The build-script can write a new .rs-file, which may include any kind of code you want.
